# Error 'tuple' object is not callable

Tags: python

Necesito crear un código que, según un salario anual que introduzca el usuario, me calcule el IRPF a pagar. Este es mi código:

```py
#De 0 hasta 12450€ ---> 19%
#De 12450 hasta 20200 ---> 24%
#De 20200 hasta 35200 ---> 30%
#De 35200 hasta 60000 ---> 37%
#Más de 60000 ---> 45%
    
ingresos_anuales = float (input("Introduce ingresos anuales: "))
   
valor1 = 0
valor2 = 12450
valor3 = 20200
valor4 = 35200
valor5 = 60000
    
tipo1 = 0.19
tipo2 = 0.24
tipo3 = 0.30
tipo4 = 0.37
tipo5 = 0.45
   
if valor1 <= ingresos_anuales <= valor2:
    IRPF = ingresos_anuales*tipo1
    print ("IRPF: ", IRPF)
elif valor2 < ingresos_anuales <= valor3:
    IRPF = ingresos_anuales*tipo2
    print ("IRPF: ", IRPF)
elif valor3 < ingresos_anuales <= valor4:
    IRPF = ingresos_anuales*tipo3
    print ("IRPF: ", IRPF)
elif valor4 < ingresos_anuales <= valor5:
    IRPF = ingresos_anuales*tipo4
    print ("IRPF: ", IRPF)
elif ingresos_anuales > valor5:
    IRPF = ingresos_anuales*tipo5
    print ("IRPF: ", IRPF)
else:
    print ("Dato no válido, vuelva a intentarlo")
    ingresos_anuales = input("Introduce ingresos anuales: ")
```

El problema es que cuando me va a imprimir el IRPF me salta el error `'tuple' object is not callable` y no se como podría solucionarlo.

Comment: version de python?

Comment: De verdad es ese todo el código? Mi impresión es que en alguna parte que no muestras has creado una variable llamada `print`, o que has olvidado cerrar algún paréntesis.

Answer (score 0):

Yo he copiado y ejecutado el código que pones y me funciona bien, sin errores. Como comentan los compañeros, ¿Podrías mostrar la salida del error y con que versión de Python trabajas?

A parte del código y ya en tema fiscal. Si quieres calcular realmente el irpf a pagar, en España el impuesto no se calcula aplicando a toda la base liquidable el mismo tipo. Es un impuesto que funciona por escalas. Voy a poner un ejemplo a ver si me explico. Suponemos una base liquidable (después de deducciones) de 50.000 €

```
| tramos | tipo impositivo | cuota |
| 1º 12.450 € | 19% | 12.450 * 0,19 = 2.365 |
| 2º de 12.450 hasta 20.200 | 24% | (20.200 - 12.450) * 0,24 = 1.860 |
| 3 de 20.200 hasta 35.200 | 30% | (35.200 - 20.200 ) * 0,30 = 4.500 |
| 4 de 35.200 hasta 50.000 | 37% | (50.000 - 35.200) * 0,37 = 5.476 |
```

Con lo que la final la cuota total es la suma de las parciales ( 2365+1860+4500+5476) = 14.201